# CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION fails silently

Tags: c#, sql-server

We have a system for creating a new database which includes the following method.

```
void CreateBaseObjects(DbConnection conn)
{
    var scripts = new ScriptManager();
    conn.Command(scripts.MainDbXmlSchemaScript).ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Command(scripts.MainDbSchemaScript).ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

`DBConnection` wraps a `SqlConnection`, but does no exception handling.  When this method is called, `conn` and is in a valid state and is connected to a newly created, empty database.

`scripts.MainDbXmlSchemaScript` is a SQL script containing a handful of `CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION ...` statements.

`scripts.MainDbSchemaScript` is a SQL script which creates tables, and their associated objects, some of which have columns that reference the XML schemas created by the first script.

Most of the time (>= 99.9%) this works without error.  Occasionally, when the second script runs we get a SqlException with the message:

> Error Number 6314 : Collection specified does not exist in metadata : 'xmlFoo'

where `xmlFoo` is the name of the first XML Schema from the first script that is referenced by a `CREATE TABLE` statement in the second script.

I know that the scripts are correct because retrying the operation after a period of time is successful.

So my question is this: is there a way that the first script could fail to create the XML schema collection objects without returning an error to the `ExecuteNonQuery()` method?

Note that this issue accurs on multiple different servers, running various versions of SQL Server (at least 2014 and 2016).

Comment: "Can this SQL script which I've not shown you fail in ways that will fail to be reported as an error back to the .NET code?" Is that really the essence of your question? And if so, how do you expect us to answer it?

Comment: I don't like this answer but when I get that error in SSMS, copying the query to a new query window lets the query go through.  I think this causes the query to run on a new connection to the SQL Server instance.